# Magento2 get products collection

Tags: php, magento2

I am trying to get **store view specific** product attribute values for all(actually filtered list but that's irrelevant) products like so:

```
<?php

/* @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory */
$collection = $collectionFactory->create()->setStoreId(3)->load();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    var_dump($product->getSku());
    var_dump($product->getName());
}
```

SKU is returned as expected(as it's general anyway) but product name is not - instead `NULL` is returned.

It works fine in adminhtml product edit [controller](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php#L61) where [builder](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Builder.php) is used. The only difference is that edit controller works with `Model\Product` model; collection for some reason works with `Model\Product\Interceptor`.
Have tried to load each product in the loop using `Model\ProductFactory`(which is how it is done in edit controller) - doing so `$product->getName()` returns corresponding value(however I was not able to get other relevant product attributes). Loading product once again in the loop is wrong off course.

So the **question**: What is the expected way of retrieving products and getting product attribute(description, weight etc) values for given store view?

Comment: Sku is static attribute which means it is in `catalog_product_entity` table. Since you are creating collection then no additional attributes are added. You probably have flat tables turned off for product and that is why no attributes are added. Try adding `->addAttributeToSelect('name')` before `load()`

Comment: @Zefiryn thanks - that does the trick. `Use Flat Catalog Product` config value is indeed `No` by default

Answer (score 11):

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager
    ->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();
            
foreach ($collection as $product){
    echo 'Name = '.$product->getName().'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Having default Magento2 setup `addAttributeToSelect('*')` does not work for some reason. Explicitly calling `addAttributeToSelect($attribute)` for each required attribute works off course

Comment: `addAttributeToSelect('*')` works for me in v2.1.2. However, instead of looping through the entire collection, what is the most efficient way to return 6 random products?

Comment: @thdoan For You to get random you need to add $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()'). To limit it to 6 then next you can add $collection->setPageSize(6); // fetching only 6